# Trying to get htmlelementcollection from web browser I get NullReferenceException that disappears if I leave the sub and I run it again

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, nullreferenceexception, mshtml

I open a webpage with webbrowser and then I submit a form.
After that I'm trying to use this code to extract data from  tags of a table:

```
Dim WebDoc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument = DirectCast(WebBrowser1.Document.DomDocument, MSHTML.IHTMLDocument)
Dim FTbl As MSHTML.IHTMLTable = WebDoc.getElementById("F")
Dim aElems As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection = FascTbl.GetElementsByTagName("a")
```

I get "NullReferenceException" on aElems (because FTbl is nothing).

But I noticed a strange thing: if (in debug) I leave the sub and execute again the three lines of code (without reloading the webpage), I do not receive errors and aElems is properly valued.

What is it that makes me appear the error in the first run?